# Docker container still downloading and executing even after a complete delete

Tags: php, apache, docker, nginx, docker-compose

Even after i stoped all docker containers and did `docker system prune -a` Docker is still downloading and executing tutum/php-apache by runing the command `docker-compose up`, here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
  postgres:
    image: camptocamp/postgres

  web:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    volumes:
      - '.:/usr/share/nginx/html
```

'
And here is runing containers:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                             NAMES
3807234b989f        camptocamp/postgres   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        5432/tcp                          ferrybox_postgres_1
551acc487c9d        tutum/apache-php      "/run.sh"                5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32786->8000/tcp   ferrybox_web_1
```

Comment: that's what docker-compose up command suppose to do (pull image, create services and run it). Were you expecting something else ?

Comment: check for container-id and created-time --- you will get it different

Comment: Maybe you didnt notice that tutum/apache-php is not declared in docker-compose.yml?

Comment: does `--force-recreate` help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`docker system prune -a` will remove all unused images , so assuming that you when executing this command - it is possible that tutum/apache-php image was used by the running-container and it was not created/started by the current docker-compose.yml file (may be docker-compose.yml file had this entry before).

```
docker@default:~$ docker system prune --help

Usage:  docker system prune [OPTIONS]

Remove unused data

Options:
  -a, --all             Remove all unused images not just dangling ones
      --filter filter   Provide filter values (e.g. 'label=<key>=<value>')
  -f, --force           Do not prompt for confirmation
      --volumes         Prune volumes
docker@default:~$
```

Can you stop the container (use container-id or name) and remove it, 

just to ensure if tutum/apache-php container was created+started again when you invoke `docker-compose up` ?

```
#>docker rm -f 3807234b989f        
#>docker rm -f 551acc487c9d        
#>docker system prune -a
#>docker-compose up
#>docker-compose ps
#>docker ps
```

Let me know if you get the same output as you were getting earlier.

Comment: I assume it works because im getting another error xD ERROR: for web  Cannot start service web: b'driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint ferrybox_web_1 (dcbb76d7c3623d2caece8909f4f76e42210c646a1de94c53f49894b185b3cbce): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80: bind: address already in use'

Comment: its because of the ports, i need to use another port for nginx because my ubuntu system already came with an installed apache